Variational quantum eigensolver tutorial
I am looking some good paper and coding tutorial for variational quantum eigensolver.
It would be great if someone can guide me on this?

Did you take a look at this?

Also, what exactly are IBM and PennyLane tutorials lacking?

Thank you for the response @FDGod. These tutorials are not good and are too abstract. Really not useful. I am looking for some well written paper or tutorial by which I can thoroughly understand the concept of VQE.

And what about the first link and paper linked therein?

Yes, the paper in the first line is good. @FDGod.

Something like that? https://docs.classiq.io/latest/explore/built_in_apps/chemistry/chemistry/

Adding summarizing to what already said in the comments and other answers -
Reviews

The Variational Quantum Eigensolver: a review of methods and best practices (This is a long review on VQA)
Variational quantum state eigensolver
Variational quantum algorithms (Comprehensive review on VQE)
Noisy intermediate-scale quantum algorithms
VQE method: a short survey and recent developments
Variational quantum algorithms: fundamental concepts, applications and challenges

Wikipedia
Tutorials

Variational quantum algorithms (IBM)
Variational quantum eigensolver (IBM)
More exercises based on Qiskit available in github rep

There are bunch of YouTube lectures on qiskit channel like this
Related

Best tutorial about the variational quantum eigensolver (VQE)


Thank you help @Himanshu.

I think this is a good qiskit tutorial.
Also, this is a book I got to know through this question, it described a fermionic creation/annihilation operators and fermion to qubit mappings in an easy way
to understand followed by a coding.

Thank you help @taketoshikinoshita

There is an entire book on how to use the VQE and QAOA to solve combinatorial optimization problems:
Hands-On Quantum Machine Learning With Python: Volume 2: Combinatorial Optimization
It thoroughly goes through all the concepts the VQE builds on

Thank you for the help @Frank Zickert.
